# Why do I get error when using diff in R on matrix

Tags: r

I read data in from a csv file using

```
d<-read.csv("myfile.csv",header=TRUE)
```

The data is read correctly and has 10 columns of double data with header.

I want to create a matrix(my word - not sure what I actually want in R) of the log differences.

```
logs<-log(d)
```

This works fine, but

```
diffs<-diff(logs)
```

gives this error:

-(length(r) - lag + 1L)   <<< I have no idea what that means...

EDIT 1 My data (sorry had to type it here - can't see an  obvious way to attach a file)

```
A,B,C
1.1,2.1,3.1
1.2,2.2,3.2
1.3,2.3,3.3
1.4,2.4,3.4
1.5,2.5,3.5
1.6,2.6,3.6
```

Comment: can you dput your data please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here (and your problem) is that while `diff` does (to my surprise) work automatically column-wise on matrices, it **doesn't** work on **data frames**, which is what you get from `read.csv` and which are subtly different from matrices.

```
d <- read.csv(textConnection("
A,B,C
1.1,2.1,3.1
1.2,2.2,3.2
1.3,2.3,3.3
1.4,2.4,3.4
1.5,2.5,3.5
1.6,2.6,3.6"))
(logs <- log(d))
diff(logs)
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

diff(as.matrix(logs))
```

My initial answer was that you should use

```
apply(logs,2,diff)
```

to explicitly use `diff` on each column. However, from `?diff`:

> x: a numeric vector or matrix containing the values to be differenced.
>   ...
>   If ‘x’ is a matrix then the difference operations are carried out on
>   each column separately.

You could also do `diff(c(as.matrix(logs)))` if you wanted to treat the whole thing as a single continuous (column-ordered) vector.

Comment: I converted to matrix by doing m<-as.matrix(d) and the diffs<-diff(m) work! That's great. BUT now plot(xvalues,m$A,type="l") does not work - do I need to specify the column name differently for a matrix?

Comment: There should be an entry in the R-FAQ that says something like "when you get 'Error... non-numeric argument to binary op...' it's usually because you've got a dataframe instead of a matrix."

Comment: @ManInMoon: the `$` only works for data frames, you should use `m[,"A"]` for matrices. *Or* use my `lapply` suggestion; then you don't need to convert to a matrix.